# Seek Bar Increase Height

Tags: android, seekbar

I am working with a `SeekBar` that works perfectly fine. But I want to increase the **height** of the Progress bar, as the native height is not as high.

So how can I change the height of the progress bar, either dynamically or through XML?

Comment: -Have you fixed the height of seekbar in XML?

Answer (score 5):

To create custom seekbar, add in your **xml file** below code:

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seek_homelayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:maxHeight="8dip"
                android:minHeight="8dip"
                android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/thumb"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/sb_progress_drawable"
                android:progressTint="@color/black"
                android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:thumb="@drawable/sb_thumb"
                android:thumbTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Create **sb_progress_drawable.xml file** in drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#26FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:scaleWidth="100%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#26FFFFFF"/>
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:scaleWidth="100%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

If you want to use thumb on to seekbar then add **sb_thumb.xml file** in your drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="12dp"
        android:height="12dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `maxHeigh` and `minHeight` attributes.
This attributes will determinate the height of your seekbar.

```
android:maxHeight="3dp" 
android:minHeight="3dp"
```

https://www.lvguowei.me/post/customize-android-seekbar-color/

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above works, simply set `android:layout_height="10dp"` to whatever value you want!

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```